# Google provisioning api returning apparently bogus error for account creation

Tags: google-provisioning-api

We use the Google Python API to create accounts.  Beginning on 11/8/2012 at 1pm PST, we
have started to get these intermittent error messages:

```
errorCode="1301" invalidInput="loginname" reason="EntityDoesNotExist"
```

When we check the Google dashboard, the account is in fact created, but the remainder of
our account creation tasks are not completed due to the error message that google sends back.

Has anyone else noticed this problem and/or have an idea why this may be happening?

Our account provisioning code is robust and has created over 50,000 accounts prior to 11/8.

Here is the code snippet:

```
r = client.CreateUser(act.localpart, family_name, given_name, password, suspended='false', quota_limit=25600, password_hash_function="SHA-1",change_password=None )
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cherrypy/_cphttptools.py", line 105, in _run
    self.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cherrypy/_cphttptools.py", line 254, in main
    body = page_handler(*virtual_path, **self.params)
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_accountgmail
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/controllers.py", line 348, i  expose
    output = database.run_with_transaction(
  File "<string>", line 5, in run_with_transaction
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/database.py", line 376, in s _rwt
    retval = dispatch_exception(e, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/database.py", line 357, in s _rwt
    retval = func(*args, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 5, in _expose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/controllers.py", line 365, i  <lambda>
    mapping, fragment, args, kw)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/controllers.py", line 393, in _execute_func
    output = errorhandling.try_call(func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/errorhandling.py", line 72, in try_call
    return func(self, *args, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_accountgmail
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/controllers.py", line 182, in validate
    return errorhandling.run_with_errors(errors, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/errorhandling.py", line 115, in run_with_errors
    return func(self, *args, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_accountgmail
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/turbogears/identity/conditions.py", line 235, in require
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/MYA/mya/account_controllers.py", line 1893, in create_accountgmail
    raise Exception('Could not create gmail account, %s: %s'%(result, act.format_address()))
Exception: Could not create gmail account, RequestError: Server responded with: 400, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppsForYourDomainErrors>
  <error errorCode="1301" invalidInput="LOGIN" reason="EntityDoesNotExist" />
</AppsForYourDomainErrors>: LOGIN@berkeley.edu
```

Answer (score 1):

Another person with the same problem filed a ticket with google and got this response:

We received the following update from Google Enterprise Support regarding the
"EntityDoesNotExist" provisioning error:

```
  It seems that it's the request to retrieve the user that is
  returning this exception. It's most likely due to a propagation
  delay in our servers: the user is correctly provisioned but the
  information isn't propagated quickly enough and the call to
  retrieve the user is made on a server where the user isn't
  provisioned yet so you get the error EntityDoesNotExist.

  As a temporary workaround until additional specialists can
  resolve the propagation issue, I suggest you ignore the requests
  that are failing with the error EntityDoesNotExist. I have added
  your case to an issue report and will be sure to update you with
  additional updates as they transpire.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem while using their .NET Library and Google support told me to stop using Client Login and use OAuth2.0.  Client login is deprecated : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

I am currently wrestling with OAuth so i can't report if it works any better.  However the issue disappeared by itself in the meantime.